# Replacing Light Switch (NZ)

Tags: switch, light

[image]

Need help replacing the old double switch (top two photos) for the new smart switch for my Grandma so she can have the lights come on at dusk till Dawn for security.

Comment: What part of the planet are you on?

Comment: @JACK -- New Zealand, apparently

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  oops, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I am (mostly...) a fan of **use the right tool for the job**.

Can a WiFi controlled smart switch be programmed to track sunrise/sunset? Sure.

But how about a simple photocell fixture? That is a far simpler technology that has been around "forever". No computer, smartphone, etc. needed. No worry about forgetting how to program it. Automatically on/off every day with sunset/sunrise.

Alternatively, you can get a motion sensor light. Automatically turns on when it detects someone within range and stays on until there is no movement for a while.

Comment: also no worry about the vendor shutting down their servers and bricking the switch

Comment: I would *hope* that a WiFi smart switch would provide a way for all programming to be done directly within the local network. But a lazy manufacturer might decide to do everything through their server so that the individual devices don't need to support a full HTML/CSS/Javascript UI. Of course, doing that means your switches are now under control of anyone who takes control of that web site...not a pleasant thought. And your average consumer would have no idea how to determine which way the device works.

Comment: Kasa (by tp-link) uses an internet server... not sure about other brands, using a server greatly simplifies setup and remote access

Comment: Using a server does simplify a lot. But if it is **only** via a server then not only do you have  a problem updating configuration if the vendor shuts down, but also if your own internet connection is down - which might be exactly the time (e.g., storm -> power outage *and* internet out, running on generator) when you want to change the configuration to meet current needs.

Comment: I read a short story by  J. G. Ballard in the 80s , and haven't wanted a smart house since.

Comment: @Jasen A far more likely scenario is it getting dark earlier (or staying dark later) due to dense cloud cover.  This can easily offset the turn on time by a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

one of 4 or 5 is the live and the other is the power feed to the lamp for switch 2

switch 1 is a multi-way switch circuit, probably the lamp end of it.

this is a guess:
2 to A2, 4 A1, 5 to A  black to N. 1 and 3 unused (use a joiner to insulate them)
if there are two groups of black use the group that the cables for 4 and 5 go to.

if switch 2 doesn't work with that swap 4 and 5

if switch 2 works and switch 1 doesn't work swap 1 and 2

Switch one was a multiway switch, you'll also have to find the other switches that were peers with switch 1 and replace them with remotes for the smart switch.